# jQuery .click() doesn't fire on particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to register when someone clicks on an arrow (it appears when you hover over the floating box) that moves from one slide to another on the main page of this site: http://questtours-dc.com but for some reason the arrows are a black hole.

I have multiple functions setup to log clicks at the moment trying to figure this out. It is a Wordpress site so I have to pass the $ in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).click(function(){
    console.log(' A click has occurred ');
  });

  $(".et-arrow-next").click(function(){
    console.log(' You clicked the arrow ');
  });

  $(".et-slider-arrows").on('click','.et-arrow-next',function(){
    console.log(' 1 - You clicked the arrow ');
  });

  $("a.et-arrow-next").on('click',function(){
    console.log(' 2 - You clicked the arrow ');
  }); 

  $('#et-slider-wrapper').on('click','.et-arrow-next', function() {
    console.log(' 3 - You clicked the arrow');
  });
});
```

When you click anywhere on the page except the two arrows that come on either side of the floating box it registers a click. But whenever you click on an arrow it registers nothing.

EDIT: This does not work either. Added after first two replies.

```
$(".et-arrow-next").on("click", function() {
  console.log(' You clicked the arrow '); 
});
```

EDIT 2: Trying to target the class after the hover has kicked in doesn't work either

```
$('#et-slider-wrapper:hover .et-slider-arrows a').on('click', function() {
  console.log(' 4 - You clicked the arrow ');
});

$('#et-slider-wrapper:hover .et-arrow-next').on('click', function() {
  console.log(' 5 - You clicked the arrow ');
});
```

Comment: Searched the theme's javascript and found that those particular arrows had a "return false" attached to them. So I assume that was what was preventing jQuery from registering a click event.

Answer (score 2):

If the element you are trying to click is dynamically generated from javascript , use

```
$( ".et-arrow-next" ).on( "click", function() {
     console.log(' You clicked the arrow ');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work either unfortunately. I had tried that before after looking at other people's questions on here about a similar issue. Have added that line to the site though to show it still doesn't log.

Comment: Is the class of element changing during hover ?

Comment: I contacted the company that makes the theme to ask if there was anything I wasn't noticing being put in front of the arrows that were blocking them, but they said the question was beyond the scope of their support.

Comment: Did you try `Inspect Element` ?  I'm sure you can fix it. :D

Comment: I'm watched Firebug while hovering over it and found the CSS rule that makes the arrows move out on either side of the box but when I use that same rule to target the arrows with jQuery it still does not log a click event.

Answer (score 0):

> it appears when you hover over the floating box

If it is appended dynamically to the page (meaning that it doesn't actually exist when the document is ready) then you have to use the `on()` method like this:

```
$(".someclass").on("click", function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the explanation but this doesn't work either. Have added it to the site's JS so that you can see it doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, doesn't register anything at all when the arrow is clicked.